# How to schedule task using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute task based on time so i am using `node-schedule` to run every 1 minute for now but i dont see anything in console, Any idea what is implemented wrong ?

cron.js

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');

cron.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('This runs at the 30th mintue of every hour. FROM NODE SCHEDULE');
    async.eachSeries(directories, function(dir, cb1) {
        var dir = __dirname + dir;
        console.log('reading', dir);
        // get files for the directory
        fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
            if (err) return cb1(err);

            // loop through each file
            async.eachSeries(files, function(file, cb2) {
                var filePath = path.resolve(dir + '/' + file);
                // get info for the file
                fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
                    if (err) return cb2(err);
                    var fileInfo = {
                        fileDate: stats.birthtime,
                        filename: file
                    };
                    console.log('fileInfo', fileInfo);
                    compareDates(fileInfo, filePath);
                    cb2(null, fileInfo);
                });
            }, cb1);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your cron expression would run every second, not every minute

Comment: but thats not even happening , this is just for testing purpose i was testing first to check if node-schedule module is working, Actual implementation i want to run every day 6:00AM if i can that example i will appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thoughts:

Here https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule is written about cron pattern: there are 6 asterisks. The first one (optional) corresponds to seconds. You need to omit one last asterisks in order to run it every minute.

Have you tried to run it first like this? Did it work?

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');

cron.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function() {
    console.log('This runs at the 30th mintue of every hour. FROM NODE SCHEDULE');
});
```

Comment: can you do the following? 1) create empty folder with testcron.js file inside with the content above. 2) do "npm install node-schedule".  3) "node testcron.js". I just tried this on my laptop and it worked fine - prints to console every minute.

Comment: Cron patter to run a job every day at 6am: 0 6 * * *

Comment: yeah if i do node testcron.js it is working , do i need to invoke testcron.js from app.js ? How ?

Comment: you should just connect it to app.js (var cron = require('path/to/your/testcron');) and then run your app.js. Your server should run if you want this cron job running.

Comment: there is another module I use called "node-cron" and it allows to explicitly start and stop it from your node.js server. But this server should be running of course.

Comment: so to run everyday 6Am i should do `06****`

Comment: no, `06***`  - you have too much asterisks again. In your version it will run every hour on 6th minute: 1:06, 2:06 and so on.

Comment: how we specify AM and PM , is it 24 hours format if want to do 11PM i can `23***`

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is 24 hours format. But it will be `0 23 * * *`

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck running other of the modules that are providing the same functionality.

See one of those modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron-job

and more modules here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/schedule
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/job

Comment: i have tried all these modules`node-cron` `node-schedule` non of these work can i get any working example so i can implement.

Comment: There is quite a lazy and unhelpful answer. There is no reason why `node-schedule` shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to run every 1 minute from now.

```
    var cron = require('node-schedule');
    cron.scheduleJob({ rule: '*/59 * * * * *' }, function () {
        console.log('This runs at the 30th mintue of every hour. FROM NODE SCHEDULE');
        /*
        async.eachSeries(directories, function (dir, cb1) {
            var dir = __dirname + dir;
            console.log('reading', dir);

            // get files for the directory
            fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
                if (err) return cb1(err);

                // loop through each file
                async.eachSeries(files, function (file, cb2) {
                    var filePath = path.resolve(dir + '/' + file);
                    // get info for the file
                    fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
                        if (err) return cb2(err);
                        var fileInfo = {
                            fileDate: stats.birthtime,
                            filename: file
                        };
                        console.log('fileInfo', fileInfo);
                        compareDates(fileInfo, filePath);
                        cb2(null, fileInfo);
                    });
                }, cb1);

            });
        });
        */
    });
```

Comment: for some reason this one did not work nothing in console

Comment: if i just do node cron.js i see the results how i will invoke . do i need to invoke this method from app.js

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers here, but it seems that your question was still not fully answered. I just created a simple project, ran the code, and it worked for me. :)

Perhaps you have skipped over one of these steps:

**1) Copy the code into a local javascript file.** 
I named mine "index.js", and in it I put this simplified version of your original code snippet:

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');

cron.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('This runs every second FROM NODE SCHEDULE');
});
```

**2) Create a package.json file for managing your dependency libraries.** 
One easy way to create this file is to run `npm init` and follow the interactive questions in your command prompt.

**3) Install the node-schedule and save it to package.json**
You can do this by running this command:
`npm install node-schedule --save`

**4) Run your javascript file.**

I ran this command:
`node index.js`

Also, here is a video of me running the file and having it log to the console:

https://vimeo.com/208851066

*Note that for illustration and testing purposes I have the cron scheduled to run every second. To have it run every minute the cron expression would be this:*
`'0 * * * * *'`

**EDIT**

If you want to call this file from within another javascript file, just wrap this node-schedule code in a function that is visible to your other javascript files.
Here is an example in Es5 syntax:

*index.js*

var cron = require('node-schedule');

```
module.exports = function beginCron() {
    cron.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function () {
        console.log('This runs every second FROM NODE SCHEDULE');
    });
};
```

*app.js*

```
var beginCron = require('./index.js');

beginCron();
```

We can then run app.js and see it beginning the cron execution like this: `node app.js`.

Comment: so you are manual running node index.js , but in real scenario how i will run it from app.js

Comment: ok it worked but last thing i want to check is to run it every day 6AM i should do *06***`

Comment: That would trigger it every second between 6am and 6:01am. To run it once per day, every day, at 6am you could do this: `'0 0 6 * * *'`